# Multi-instance COM object creation

Tags: permissions, com, windows-services, dcom, opc

I have a server which has an OPC server. As i understand it is a simple COM object. DCOM is configured and works well. I can simple connect to this OPC server from other PC using the same login and password (my PC's is not in the domain). If i will connect throw DCOM to the server OPC server process will be created automatically. If i will login to the server under the user which can access OPC object and will connect to it i will get one more OPC server process. And it is a problem. I need only one instance per PC. The same problem will occur if i will install a couple of windows services under the same user which has access to the OPC server object. Every service will create it's one OPC server object process. If i'm connecting throw DCOM using different applications from one machine i will only one process for this machine. OPC server object is a third party. DCOM identity can't be configured to use system account because this radio button is blocked in config window (it is in russian but i think you can understand the picture):
[image]

How can i solve this problem? How can i configure system do not create new instance of an COM OPC server object if it is already exists? Is it possible?

Update 1. I have tried to call CoCreateInstanceTwice as @IgorTandetnik suggested but i have got only instance. It means that server working in multi use mode. Test code:

```
static void CoCreateInstanceTwice()
{
    Guid guid = new Guid("39C13A4D-011E-11D0-9675-0020AFD8ADB3");
    IntPtr intPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr outPtr;
    try
    {

        var res = CoCreateInstance(
            new Guid("AEDE6AB0-95F9-11D4-BF93-0050BAC23960"),
            intPtr,
            4,
            guid,
            out outPtr
            );
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }

    Guid guid1 = new Guid("39C13A4D-011E-11D0-9675-0020AFD8ADB3");
    IntPtr intPtr1 = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr outPtr1;
    try
    {

        var res = CoCreateInstance(
            new Guid("AEDE6AB0-95F9-11D4-BF93-0050BAC23960"),
            intPtr1,
            4,
            guid1,
            out outPtr1
            );
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    ReadLine();        
}

[DllImport("ole32.dll", EntryPoint = "CoCreateInstance", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern HRESULT CoCreateInstance(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rclsid,
    IntPtr pUnkOuter,
    UInt32 dwClsContext,
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid,
    out IntPtr ppv
);
```

Both calls returns success. I forgot to mention that to communicate with this COM component i'm using another one COM component (in-process) throw which i'm connecting to the server.
The result is the same. Throw one logon session i can use one one object but throw two or more system creates for each session it's own object event if both sessions from one user.

Comment: In the dialog you have shown, set the server to run under a specific user account.

Comment: @ZbynekZ, i have tried to do this. I was trying different users but result was the same.

Comment: What does your server pass to `CoRegisterClassObject`? Not `REGCLS_SINGLEUSE`, by any chance?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, the server is third party component. I know only one way to detect what is passing to `CoRegisterClassObject` - disassembling. I have found out an article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/169321 and i have tried many variants but nothing working. I think your suggestion is right and developers of component were using `REGCLS_SINGLEUSE`.

Comment: It's easy to test. Write a simple program that calls `CoCreateInstance` on this server twice, then sleeps for a few minutes (to give you a chance to look at Task Manager). See if this results in two copies for the server EXE running - that's a sure sign of `REGCLS_SINGLEUSE`. If confirmed, you can reclassify this behavior from "a problem" to  "working as intended" and move on.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, added results to question